# How to get capturing groups of a regular expression object in JavaScript/Node without matching anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regex-group

Having a JavaScript RegExp object is there a way to get a list of capturing groups without having a string that matches the regular expression? For instance in

```js
const pattern = '(?<start>fo+).*(bar)'
const regex = RegExp(pattern)
```

The capturing groups are `"start"` and `1`. It looks like `RegExp` does not provide an accessor method to get all groups, so I think the `pattern` needs to be analyzed.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but you might look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/regexpp